# How do i set the select value of a drop down?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following code to load a `dropdownlist` with `json` data

```
    $('#btnAddNew').click(function (evt) {

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployee","Employee")',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //edit form's ddl 
                $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').empty();
                console.log(data);
                $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                    //edit forms ddl
                    $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').append($('<option/>', { text: item.Description, value: item.ID }));
                });
            },
            error: function () { }
        });



        $('#empID').val('');
        $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').val('2');
        $('#txtFirstName').val('');
        $('#txtLastName').val('');
        $('#txtDOB').val('');
        $('#txtSalary').val('');
        $('#cbIsMarried').prop('checked', false);


        form.dialog('open');

        resetValidations();
        form.show();          

    });
```

the line  `$('#ddlEmployeeCategories').val('2');` set the selected item to the item of value '2' (NOT the INDEX). but this does not set selected item. why?

Comment: You have an async call that populates the dropdown. The time you change the value of dropdown the item probably does not exist. You should move that code inside ajax call.

Comment: @AlexChar sorry i don't follow!

Comment: Your async call populates the dropdown with id `#ddlEmployeeCategories`. But you try to select a value that probably does not exist yet. You can move the `$('#ddlEmployeeCategories').val('2');` inside ajax call when success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the values after ajax call returns success:

```
$('#btnAddNew').click(function(evt) {

    $.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployee","Employee")',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //edit form's ddl 
            $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').empty();
            console.log(data);
            $(data).each(function(index, item) {
                //edit forms ddl
                $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').append($('<option/>', {
                    text: item.Description,
                    value: item.ID
                }));
            });

            $('#empID').val('');
            $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').val('2');
            $('#txtFirstName').val('');
            $('#txtLastName').val('');
            $('#txtDOB').val('');
            $('#txtSalary').val('');
            $('#cbIsMarried').prop('checked', false);


            form.dialog('open');

            resetValidations();
            form.show();
        },
        error: function() {}
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `success` to:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').empty();
  $(data).each(function (index, item) {
    $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').append($('<option/>', { text: item.Description, value: item.ID }));
  });
  $('#ddlEmployeeCategories').val('2');
  ... // your other code
}
```

You must set that item when you are certain that your ajax call has finished.

Comment: So at any occasion when i need to set the value of this type of dropdowns either to set value comming from a datatable to assign that value with these drop downs i must put in in the ajax that created a dropdown list?

Comment: Well, when you are making _asynchronous HTTP (Ajax)_ requests, like `$.ajax()` you should you use the `success` callback function for stuff you want to do only after and if the request was succesful (otherwise there are no items to select).